# Android - getting BLE and WiFi work together

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

We are working on a BLE device and have an android app to control/configure it.

The BLE connections seem to have problem with some android devices which have 4.4 updates. The connection/disconnections happen very frequently when the WiFi on the android device is ON. 
When the WiFi is turned off the frequency is reduced dramatically. 
Also on Nexus 5 when the WiFi is forced to use 2.4GHz, the frequency of connections/disconnections is reduced.

But the option to change the WiFi settings is not available on all phones (like Moto G).

What is the fix for this?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Same, while it's comes as the internal hardware problems with the antenna or the internal frequency channel distribution problem. Yet to be resolved.